# Form Builder with JQuery Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

Im looking for a really good form builder like http://jotform.com but one that uses JQuery for validation.

The things I like is the really easy drag and drop and the speed at which forms can be created and then I can grab the code and put it on a site.

Jotform uses Prototype and it conflicts with JQuery.

Is there one avaliable?

Comment: You can use JQuery.noConflict(); to avoid conflicts http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I never thought of that! Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to use JotForm on a page that uses jquery. Simply use the IFrame Code option. Here is how you can do it:

On [JotForm Form Builder](http://www.jotform.com/):

1. Click on "Source Code" button on the "Setup & Share" toolbar,
2. Click on "Advanced Options" button on the wizard screen,
3. Choose "IFrame Code" option and copy it to your web site.

Since the form is served within an IFrame there is no way for it to conflict with anything else on the page.

We are also working on a solution to make sure the regular JotForm javascript and full source code to work on a jquery page.

I hope you will stay with us! :)

Comment: Thanks. I really like Jotform and I will definately be continuing to use it for my web work.

Comment: JotForm shares the source code of the generated form as well. Thus, freely tweak it as per your needs!

Answer (score 1):

The best one I have found so far is:

http://www.phpform.org/formbuilder/index.php

They also have a paid version too where you can get the source code.

Comment: I would suggest [JotForm](http://jotform.com). As it provides the Source Code to free users as well.